# Compiling: libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing, already included -lm

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, mpi

I try to compile a library, which works fine on a cluster. However, when I try to compile it locally on my private laptop I get the following error:

`/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/zfs.dir/zfsstrctrdblck3d.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'tanhl@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing`

So, what I've tried is to google (obviously) and I've found that I have to include `-lm` flag when compiling with gcc or respectively mpicc. I tried several positions of the flag, but none of them could fix the error. What else can cause this error?

My mpicc version is:
`gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0`

Thanks in advance,

Max

Comment: try to install libc6:i386 using "sudo apt-get install libc6:i386", it seems it is looking for 32bit library

Comment: Hey guys,
indeed I'm using cmake, exuse me please, I should have mention that in the initial post. I tried the following:


- adding to the CMakeLists.txt
  `add_executable(ZFS ${SRC_DIR})
    set_target_properties(ZFS PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
    target_link_libraries(ZFS m)`


- and I tried:
  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6:i386`

Comment: that can happen if your program uses `tanhl` and is not linked with `libm` but assumes depending on an other library that depends on `libm` will do the trick.

Comment: Hey @GillesGouaillardet thank you for your comment. I think it's almost clear where the problem comes from, it's just about how to fix it. All of the suggestions here and in other posts unfortunately doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out using a mismatched c and C++ compiler versions.

Problem, different versions, printed from Make file

```
CC:        cc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
CXX:       gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0
```

This was due to different versions of GCC in my computer collected over time

```
alex@pop-os:/ssd/llama.cpp$ dpkg --list | grep compiler
ii  clang                                            1:14.0-55~exp2                                                  amd64        C, C++ and Objective-C compiler (LLVM based), clang binary
ii  clang-14                                         1:14.0.0-1ubuntu1                                               amd64        C, C++ and Objective-C compiler
ii  g++                                              4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1                                               amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-11                                           11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1                                         amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-12                                           12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04                                           amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  g++-9                                            9.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04                                            amd64        GNU C++ compiler
ii  gcc                                              4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1                                               amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-11                                           11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1                                         amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-12                                           12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04
```

Corrected this by setting the following Environment variable in front of the make file

```
export CC=gcc-12
export CXX=g++-12
```

If you have CLang compiler instead of GCC or LLVM Compiler infra with Clang, you could also set

```
export CC=clang-14
export CXX=clang++-14
```

After this Make file prints correctly and make happen properly.

```
I LDFLAGS:   -lcuda -lcublas -lculibos -lcudart -lcublasLt -lpthread -ldl -lrt -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/targets/x86_64-linux/lib -L/usr/lib/wsl/lib 
I CC:        gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0
I CXX:       g++-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0
I NVCC:      Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0
```

If you want to install gcc and g++ version you can do this via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-12  # C-Compiler
sudo apt-get install g++-12  # c++ -Compiler
```

Note that after installing g++ and running make with the above setting, you may get the error

`gcc: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or director`

The cc1plus executable, which is  C++ compiler backend for GCC and may not be in path. For this add PATH explicitly

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12:$PATH
```

Note I also installed for this error first and it did not help, but putting it here as I did not remove it.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

Also added `-lm` flag to the make file to link, but that also did not help and removed it.